# Create Image from Div

Tags: javascript, canvas, html5-canvas

I'am new to canvas. I was using the following code to insert a image in canvas from another image. When I try to create image from a div using the code

```
 <!DOCTYPE html><html> 
        <head> 
            <title>test</title> 
            <script type="text/javascript">
            var colour="#ccc",bgcolour="#fff";
            function paint(hhh){
               canvas = document.getElementById('canvas'); 
               ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
               var img=document.getElementById('mine');
               ctx.drawImage(img,0,0);
            }
        </script> 
        </head> 
        <body  onload="paint('scribble');"  >
            <canvas id="canvas" style="border:solid 1px;" width="400" height="400">g</canvas>  <div id="mine">canvas</div>
        </body> 
    </html>
```

It is not working.
**My question is how to draw a image from div instead of another image?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only images you may draw with drawImage on a Canvas, are those declared in "src" attributes of a image object. Specifications may be [found here](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_img_src.asp).

I don't know any method to put the contents of a div tag inside of an image object and I don't think this is really an easy thing to do. You should think about alternatives...

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you can't draw to the canvas from an element that isn't an image, or another canvas element. Check out this MDN article for some more information **[Using images with canvas](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Canvas_tutorial/Using_images)**

Another issue is you are treating a div like an image in your events, divs do not have an `onload` event.

Comment: @MichelleSmith thats because you *cannot* draw from anything other than a canvas or image.